# XAML, display HTML without URI

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-store-apps

I'm retrieving a load of emails from a web-service which are to be displayed in a Windows Store application. The email data is of course in HTML so I would like to be able to display the email without the ML after the HT.

The problem I'm facing is filling a WebView with the content property rather than needing a URI the WebView retrieves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, this is for a Windows Store app and not for WPF. WinRT does not support FlowDocument

Answer (score 0):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7

Scenario 2

View:

```
<WebView x:Name="WebView"/>
```

Code behind:

```
WebView.NavigateToString("<html><body>Goes Here</body></html>");
```